# Nginx 1.6 + php5-fpm socket communication fail

Tags: sockets, nginx

I have problem with Nginx and PHP5-fpm, if I configure Nginx 1.2.1 everything is fine, but if I upgrade to 1.6 I have only blank page. Cany anyone say why?

Socket is created fine.
Html pages working
If i see network in Chrome i have 200OK
In PHP is only:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

My confing files:

/etc/nginx/conf.d/web.conf

```
server {

listen 192.168.99.127:8080;
server_name sub.localhost;


root /home/clients_ssl/sub/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location ~ \.php$ {

fastcgi_pass unix:/etc/php5/fpm/socks/ssl_sub.sock;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param HTTPS on;

}

location ~ /\. {
deny all;
}

access_log /home/clients_ssl/sub/logs/access.log;
error_log /home/clients_ssl/sub/logs/error.log;
error_page 404 /404.html;

}
```

---

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections 1024;
}


http {
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

sendfile on;
#tcp_nopush on;

keepalive_timeout 65;

#gzip on;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/web.conf

```
[ssl_sub]

listen = /etc/php5/fpm/socks/ssl_sub.sock
user = nginx
group = nginx
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_requests = 0
php_admin_value[open_basedir]=/
php_admin_value[session.save_path]=/home/clients_ssl/sub/tmp
php_admin_value[upload_tmp_dir]=/home/clients_ssl/sub/tmp
php_admin_value[disable_functions]=dl

listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```

((( if i change lister.owner/group and user/group to other system user for example USER0 i have error 502 bad gateway, where is problem? ))))

/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;

fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param HTTPS $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 200;
```

Comment: Have you checked whether even exists this file? `(/etc/php5/fpm/socks/ssl_sub.sock)`

Comment: /etc/php5/fpm/socks/ssl_sub.sock exist: srw-rw---- 1 nginx nginx 0 kvě 16 17:49 ssl_sub.sock

Comment: No ideas how to solve?

Comment: what OS you have? you may have compatibility issue. if you use Debian wheezy, for example, there is Nginx requirements in order to work with the distribution. meaning the libraries have to be compatible with Nginx so that it works without issues.

Answer (score 5):

If you have upgraded nginx by including

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx
```

in your /etc/apt/sources.list file, you won't have a copy of fastcgi.conf in your /etc/nginx folder.

Find the file `fastcgi_params` in /etc/nginx and add this line:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

to the top of the file. Rename the file to `fastcgi.conf`

Then, you can replace `include fastcgi_params;` to `include fastcgi.conf;` in your .conf file's php location block.

Comment: I think this should be accepted as the write answer !
Here is the detailed link to the bug introduced by upgrading to Nginx 1.6.1 and above -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/nginx/+bug/1366651
Installing from scratch shouldnt cause an issue only upgrading and accepting to keep our current configuration causes this bug.

Answer (score 2):

I had also some problems after update nginx 1.2 to 1.6

I got this information (see below), when I install wheezy-backports main contrib non-free

I put to this list: **/etc/apt/sources.list**

that source:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib non-free
```

Information by the installation:

> Fastcgi configuration issues   ============================
>
> nginx shipped a modified `fastcgi_params`, which declared
>   `SCRIPT_FILENAME`   fastcgi_param. This line has now been removed.
>   From now on we are also   shipping fastcgi.conf from the upstream
>   repository, which includes a sane   `SCRIPT_FILENAME` parameter value.
>
> So, if you are using fastcgi_params, you can try switching to
>   fastcgi.conf   or manually set the relevant params.

So I made a change in **etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

I changed `include fastcgi_params;` to `include fastcgi.conf;`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    }
```

Afterwards, restart php5-fpm and nginx

My php formular / form now works again in nginx 1.6.2